# Lookup Value in Access

Tags: ms-access

I'm trying to do a lookup of a field form one table, to update values in another table. I know this can be done easily with a query, but is there a way to do it in a table?

Basically all I'm trying to do is an excel VLOOKUP but in Access. Where if I change the lookup value in my destination table, the value returned will be updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join the tables in a query and then set the values of a field in one table to the field in the second table based on the join fields (hope that made sense).

So, for example, if you have:
`Table1` with `KeyField1` and `DescriptionField1`
`Table2` with `KeyField2` and `DescriptionField2`

If you want to update `DescriptionField1` with the values in `DescriptionField2` *where* the KeyField values match you use this SQL:

```
UPDATE Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.KeyField1 = Table2.KeyField2
SET Table1.DescriptionField1 = Table2.DescriptionField2
```

The other way is to use a look up field - select `Lookup Wizard` in the `Data Type`.
If taking this route I'd advise the ten commandments of Access tables :)

> Thou shalt never allow thy users to see or edit tables directly, but
>   only through forms and thou shalt abhor the use of "Lookup Fields"
>   which art the creation of the Evil One.
>   http://access.mvps.org/access/tencommandments.htm

Comment: I did it the first way you suggested, however I need that field to display in Table1. Therefore, sould I do this via the lookup wizard?

Comment: nevermind I didn't realize the field had updated correctly to the values I want. Now, my final question is the following:

Let's say I change 4 values in the source table, then when I run the query to link both tables, sometimes not all the values are updated. Do you happen to know if there's a reason for this?

Comment: It sounds like you want to use the lookup wizard.  I've found problems with this in the past though - the table still holds the original value, and not the looked up value (it just displays that) so if you copy out to Excel you get the original value and any query built on that table must use the original value - the lookup value is just to look at and causes confusion as to what value is actually in the field.

Comment: Are the values exactly as expected?  If you're using dates the times may be included but not displayed.  So if you're searching for 4th March, but the field holds 4th March 15:00:00 you won't get a match.

Comment: yes the values are displaying exactly as expected. I noticed that if I close the table I want to update prior to running the query, the update works perfectly. So I guess that could be the issue here.

Comment: That'll be the problem - you just need to refresh the view of the table to see the updated values. Happy to help. :)